# React - React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and having a issue with rendering elements. I have a heatmap component which I'n getting the code from external script, and calling it from my main component. Looks like I'm missing some parameter to be passed or error in the way I'm returning the element.

I have a Heatmap component :

```js
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var AmCharts = require("amcharts3-react");

// Generate random data
function generateData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();

  var dataProvider = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    var date = new Date(firstDate.getTime());

    date.setDate(i);

    dataProvider.push({
      date: date,
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    });
  }

  return dataProvider;
}


// Component which contains the dynamic state for the chart
var Chart = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      dataProvider: generateData(),
      timer: null
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var self = this;

    self.setState({
      // Update the chart dataProvider every 3 seconds
      timer: setInterval(function () {
        self.setState({
          dataProvider: generateData()
        });
      }, 3000)
    });
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);
  },

  render: function () {
    // Render the chart
    return React.createElement(AmCharts, {
      "path": "node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts",
      "type": "serial",
      "theme": "light",
      "marginRight": 40,
      "marginLeft": 40,
      "autoMarginOffset": 20,
      "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
      "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "ignoreAxisWidth": true
      }],
      "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
      },
      "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "balloon":{
          "drop": true,
          "adjustBorderColor": false,
          "color":"#ffffff"
        },
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 5,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "title": "red line",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "value",
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
      }],
      "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph": "g1",
        "oppositeAxis": false,
        "offset":30,
        "scrollbarHeight": 80,
        "backgroundAlpha": 0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha": 0,
        "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
        "autoGridCount": true,
        "color":"#AAAAAA"
      },
      "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha":1,
        "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
        "limitToGraph":"g1",
        "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
        "valueZoomable": true
      },
      "valueScrollbar":{
        "oppositeAxis": false,
        "offset":50,
        "scrollbarHeight":10
      },
      "categoryField": "date",
      "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true
      },
      "dataProvider": this.state.dataProvider
    });
  }
});
```

I'm calling it from my main component :

```js
import React from "react"
import Heatmap from "../../Elements/AmCharts/Heatmap"

...

export default class Stats extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
        ....
        <Heatmap />
        ....
      )
  }
}
```

I'm getting a error saying `warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of Stats.`

and also

`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of Stats.`

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You have not exported the `Chart` variable from `"../../Elements/AmCharts/Heatmap"` ! ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your component:

```
export default Chart = React.createClass({
```